# Firefox 3.6/Opera 10.50/IE 8 support in 2018 and beyond

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-8, opera

For a simple blog engine that will use plain JS and HTML and aims to be compatible with as many browsers as possible, still even a bit worth to mention/care about backwards compatibility with these 8+ YO browsers?

(If anyone knows a reliable data chart about detailed browser market share, I would really thank, I found just this one http://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share/desktop/worldwide)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a lightweight solution like [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/) be more forward compatible?
Whichever solution you end up choosing, it shouldn't be a bother: setup and go.

Once that's settled, I would recommend to **test** whether the key features of your blog engine are usable on these browsers:

- Internet Explorer 8
- Firefox 3.5
- Opera 12
- Safari 5.1.7

You will probably end up with a list of issues for each of these; that's when you will decide which browsers you will support.